# How do I install the actkbd command line tool?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I'm trying to connect a secondary keyboard to my computer so that I can have an additional keyboard for using macros.  I have been following [this tutorial,](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/8geyru/diy_linux_macro_board/) but I have been unable to get actkbd to work.

Here's how I installed it:  I downloaded it from [here,](https://github.com/thkala/actkbd) opened the file to the desktop, entered the directory in a terminal window, ran `make` and `sudo make install`, in that order, and then tried to execute the command `sudo actkbd -s -d /dev/input/[event]` (as described by the tutorial above,) but it fails to work, citing that bash could not find the command.

How can I get this to work?  Did I do something wrong in the installation proccess?  Any help will be appreciated.

Here are some screenshots of the output (I can't copy and paste from the terminal:)

[i.imgur.com/doB6tUt.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzkjW.png)

[i.imgur.com/IKMxd4e.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jC1S.png)

Comment: Did the `make` complete successfully?  likewise the `make install`?  The subsequent commands cannot be executed unless the prior command succeeded; and you may have had messages telling you -devel (-dev) packages were needed for the install to complete. Read the messages for your commands.

Comment: Please post the output of the make command, or record everything you do in the terminal using the "script" command and then post the results.

Comment: I have added screenshots to the post, showing the output of "make."